# Couldn't pass root component props to children components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-v4

I'm fairly beginner in react/redux, and I'm creating a simple project using React, Redux and React Router v4. I use Redux to handle the state and it sucessfully passes states to root component Wrapper, but it seems it doesn't pass it to Home or other components. 
When I console log this.props.Gallery in Wrapper, the data displays but when I do it on Gallery, it shows 'undefined'. I've passed children in Wrapper using React.cloneElement but it didn't work. Is there an explanation to this and some workaround?

My app project structure is

```
--wrapper
 -home
   -gallery
   -about
   -links
```

Here are the components

For Routing
App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

import Wrapper from './components/Wrapper';
...

//import store
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import store , {history} from './store'


//router 
const mainRouter=(
<Provider store={store} history={history}>
    <Wrapper>
  <BrowserRouter>
     <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={ Home } />
      <Route path='/portfolio' component={ Gallery } />
      <Route path='/about' component={ About } />
      <Route path='/links' component={ Links } />
    </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </Wrapper>
    </Provider>
  )

ReactDOM.render(mainRouter, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Wrapper

```
import React from 'react'
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import * as actionCreators from '../actions/actionCreators'


function mapStateToProps(state){
    return{
        gallery:state.gallery
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators(actionCreators,dispatch)
}


class Wrapper extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)}
            </div>
            )
    }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Wrapper)
```

Home.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

//import component
...


class Home extends React.Component {

render(){
    console.log(this.props.gallery)
    return(
      <div>
      <p>this is home page</p>
    <Header/>
    <Nav/>
    <Footer/>
      </div>
      )
    }
}


export default Home;
```

**Update 9/19**
I've managed to created nested components in react router v4, but still unable to pass props to its direct children. It throws an error of children being undefined

And i've also updated my component structure to

```
--Home ~ this is more like a welcome containing app's menu
--Wrapper
  -gallery
  -about
  -links
```

Here is what I did: I've moved Wrapper to be wrapper of gallery, about and links

App.js

```
<Provider store={store} history={history}>
  <BrowserRouter>
       <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/h" component={Wrapper}/>
       </div>
   </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
```

Wrapper.js

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
  return{
    gallery:state.gallery
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators(actionCreators,dispatch)
}


class HomePage extends React.Component {

render() {
  return(
  <div>
       <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/portfolio`} component={ Gallery } />
       <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/about`} component={ About } />
       <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/links`} component={ Links } />

  </div>
)
}
}
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Wrapper)
```

Comment: could you try `{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {...this.props} )}`? It's essentially the same thing as you were doing, but we are creating new object here rather than sending the reference of existing one.

Comment: I just tried it and It throws an error, unexpected token {...this.props}

Comment: I suppose you are using es6 js using `babel` and have relevant presets. like `react`, `stage-2`, `es2015`?

Comment: Yes, I have all relevant presets except for stage-2? is it necessary?

Comment: Do I understand correctly, you want to see parent props in deep nested children? In react, props aren't passed to deep children, you need to pass them throught. In your code  the wrapper props are only accessible in wrapper and in BrowserHistory(as direct child of browser history and you pass props into it explicitly)

Comment: see, [stage-2](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/), it includes all plugins from [stage-3](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-3/), which have [Object rest spread transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/), what we need here.

Comment: Ive installed stage-2, and it fixed the error, but still shows undefined when I console.log(this.props.gallery) in Home or Gallery component.

Comment: @wakwak, yes I want to pass props from wrapper to all the other components, and there have been articles that using react.cloneElement would make it happen and I've seen it works in other tutorials, but it wouldn't here. so im wondering why? the new things that changed that ive upgraded to react router v4

Comment: interesting, can you give a link to such a tutorials. I found that some people were using react.cloneElement for passing props from parent to only its children(not deep nested children). And its kind what you do in your code.. just console.log(this.props.children) in wrapper component and you'll see only BrowserHistory as a child. Usually, for deep nesting props injecting React.Context is used https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html . But it's not a good practice for your purposes. Do you really need gallery in all components in your app?

Comment: React router 4 works with components composition. so in youre Home components you can see only the router props, since Route is a parent and provide it to Home..its Like `<Route render=( (routerProps) => <Home {...routerProps} { //you can inject some additional here also..like your gallery though) } /> .... But i think its much better for you just use Wrapper container somewhere deeper in the tree, where you really need it.

Comment: [reduxstragram](https://github.com/TzolkinB/Reduxstragram) but I suppose this tutorial passes props from parent to childs. i don't need gallery in all components per se, but I do need wrapper to be able to pass props to all components as gallery is just one state in store (im just testing for one state if it works I will add others links and pod )

Comment: Thank you for the infos. I think I should restructure my components so that they get all props from redux state. I will give feedback when I do.

Comment: As you can see in that tutorial.. clone elements provides props from App to only `one level` of children (to PhotoGrid and  and Single).. inside those components the authour explicity pass down props to its children as {...this.props}.  The way its working there though, because in react-router 0-3 <Route /> is not a component under the hood, its more different code just wrapped in  jsx as helper so there's no gap between < <App />  and <Photogrid />, <Signle />., but rr4 is different. in rr4 <Route /> is a component that render another component

Comment: the way you need to structure you code should be somethign like this: <Home> 
   <GalleryContainer><Gallery /></GalleryContainer >
   <OtherStuffContainer><OtherStuff></OtherStuffContainer> </Home>

Comment: I've updated my solution. I have changed the structure but still no way to pass props to children components. any input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to pass the props to child components.

I created two containers for my project, one as main container and other as parent to sub components Gallery, About and Links.

Here is structure in App.js

```
const mainRouter=(
    <Wrapper>
<Provider store={store} history={history}>
  <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/h" component={Container}/>
       </div>
   </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
    </Wrapper>
  )
```

Then in `Container`, I connected it to redux, and created route to its sub children components and used render to render the components and pass gallery props to `Gallery`

```
<Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/portfolio`} render={()=><Gallery {...this.props.gallery}/>}/>
```

Here is the Container

```
import React from 'react'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import * as actionCreators from '../actions/actionCreators'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'


//import components
...

function mapStateToProps(state) {
      return {
        gallery: state.gallery
      }
    }

    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
      return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
    }


    class Container extends React.Component {


      render() {

        return (
          <div>
            <ResponsiveNav/>
            <main>
              <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/portfolio`}
              render={ ()=><Gallery{...this.props}/> } />
             <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/links`}
              render={ ()=><Link{...this.props}/> } />
              <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/about`}
              render={ ()=><About{...this.props}/> } />

            </main>
            <Footer/>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
    export default connect(
      mapStateToProps,
      mapDispatchToProps
    )(Container)
```

Comment: Thanks, using `render={ () => <MyComponent {...props} /> }` really helped me tie together my redux + react-router app. I don't know why they don't show the `render={ () => {...} }` alternative to `compontent={...}` in the React-Router docs pages for Quick Start, Basic example, or even the Redux Integration

Answer (score 1):

You are correctly passing the props from `Wrapper` down to it's children.  However, `Home` and `Gallery` are not it's children.  They are great great grand children.  The only child of `Wrapper` is the element(s) directly within it.  In this case, that is `BrowserRouter`.

There are a great number of ways that you could make these props available to `Home` and `Gallery`.  But passing directly from `Wrapper` is not one of them.

The simplest way would be to make a `GalleryContainer` class.  This would be identical to the `Wrapper` class you already created (include it's connections to redux), except that it would explicitly render `Gallery`, as such;

```
render() {
    return <Gallery {...this.props}/>;
}
```

Then use this new `GalleryContainer` as the component for the `/portfolio` route.

Comment: update: while this solution pass props to sub children, its not the solution i'm looking for. I want to render three component in GalleryContainer once they're clicked on in nav and by doing this solution, it renders them all in one place. What are the other ways to pass props to deep nested children components?